# in android: retrieve data from dynamically added fields in form

Tags: android, dynamic, textfield, data-retrieval

I am trying to develop a user input form where i take his details and store them
in the form i have fields for his name, email, address, phone number etc.
a person may have multiple emails or multiple phone numbers.
he can add a field by clicking a button.

and then i want to store the data entered by the user in a shared preference.

i have a question:

```
how do i retrieve data from dynamically added extra fields by the user?
I have maintained a count for dynamically added fields for each field criteria (like email, phone etc)

 but i am stuck at the point where i am supposed to retrieve the data when i need to store them in Shared Preferences.
```

Please help! thankyou in advance.

Is it possible using something like ParentViewGroup.getChildCount() or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` methods to retrieve child from a `ViewGroup`.

However, I think the better way is to save the references to the Views you added when you add them into the View hierarchy, and get data from these references.

Comment: thankyou Henry. can you give a simple hint on 'how to save the references when i add them to view hierarchy?'